# Can I make my class play nice with the Python '"in" keyword?

Tags: python

I'm heading into hour 5 or so of my experience with Python, and so far I've been pretty impressed with what it can do. My current endeavor is to make a short attempt at a Stream class, the code for which follows:

```
class Stream:

    """A Basic class implementing the stream abstraction. """

    def __init__(self,data,funct):
        self.current = data
        self._f = funct

    def stream_first(self):
        """Returns the first element of the stream"""
        return self.current

    def stream_pop(self):
        """Removes and returns the first element of the stream. """
        temp = self.current
        self.current = self._f(self.current)
        return temp
```

Enjoying modest success there, I tried to make a BoundedStream class which behaves basically like the unbounded one, except that at a certain point it runs out of elements. My question now is, seeing that any such Bounded Stream has some finite number of elements, it should be possible to iterate over them. If I were using an explicit list, I could use Python's `in` keyword and a `for` loop to do this cleanly. I would like to preserve that cleanliness for my own class. Is there some method I could implement, or any other language feature, that would allow me to do this? Any answers or other help you might provide to a rookie would be greatly appreciated!

-David

P.S.

For those who want to know, the impetus for a Bounded Stream is that I tried the builtin `range` function, but Python claimed that the range I wanted to look at was too large. I have turned to Streams in the interest of memory efficiency.

Comment: *Python claimed that the range I wanted to look at was too large* - Can you remember exactly how Python phrased that claim that it made? It would be very interesting to see your code and the resulting error.

Comment: How would you like or plan on defining the bounds of your `BoundedStream` class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For iterating as in  `for x in object`, you need to provide an `__iter__` method which will return a new iterator.

An iterator is an object which has a method `next()` (Python 2) or `__next__` (Python 3) which either returns the next element or raises `StopIteration` exception when there are no more elements. (An iterator should also have a method `__iter__` that returns itself.)

> Tip: You don't often need to code an iterator by yourself; the simplest way to implement `__iter__` on a class is to make it a [`generator function`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) or to return a generator expression from it (all generators are iterators). Also you can just return an iterator obtained from another object;  the `iter` builtin is helpful here.

---

For testing `if x in object`, you need to provide a `__contains__` method.

Further reading: [Python data model - emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

Comment: Thanks Kos! This is exactly what I was looking for. And thanks to everyone for quick answers and good details.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll be happy if you tick the green tick to the left, that's how we mark accepted answers on SO. This will also mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried the builtin range function, but Python claimed that the range I wanted to look at was too large.

Try `xrange` instead.  This requires O(1) memory because it doesn't actually create the list of numbers, it just creates an object that behaves like a list of numbers. In other words, what you are trying to do is already available.

```
>>> 5 in range(10**9)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> 5 in xrange(10**9)
True
```

Notes

- In Python 3 this isn't even an issue - xrange has been removed and range now does what xrange did in Python 2.x.)
- xrange does allows you to create very large ranges, but not arbitrarily large unfortunately. There is still a limit.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to @Kos's answer, the [Python Data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) has more functions that allow you to emulate other types, including the documentation for the [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) and [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) methods mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

To turn your class into an iterable, you need to add this method

```
def __iter__(self):
    while True:
        yield self.stream_pop()
```

Note that this doesn't require the stream to be bounded. It will work fine for unbounded streams too